# C# .Net Framework Class Library proj - Newtonsoft.Json gives "The system cannot find the file specified..." error

Tags: json, .net, api, restsharp, idispatch

The project is a Class Library which I want to use it from a Visual Foxpro application.  Visual Foxpro is 32bit.

.Net project:

- Target framework .Net Framework 4.7.2
- Target Platform x86.
- Using Newtonsoft.Json and RestSharp

I registered the DLL using RegAsm and I am able to create an object of that from Visual Foxpro.  Things are fine, if I simply do some string manipulation and I am getting return value from DLL into Visual Foxpro program.

Now, when I enable RestSharp, it breaks and throws below error:

*OLE IDispatch exception code 0 from System.Memory: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified...
*
I am not sure how this version conflict came up when I installed packages afresh and have not copied any file manually.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance
Rajesh

My Visual Foxpro test folder is different and I have copied all files from my .Net Debug folder into that folder.

Comment: You may not have that DLL accesible from GAC. You could try register ir with gacutils. Or try putting it in the .exe folder.

Comment: Use Fusion++ to create a log of what assemblies .NET Framework is trying to load and where it is looking for them: https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion/releases

Comment: @gonzalorf, my test folder is different where I have my Visual Foxpro program.  Each time I build .Net DLL, I copy all files from my Debug folder to this test folder.  So, as you assume, it should find the DLL there, isn't it?

Comment: @ChristofWollenhaupt, thank you.  Let me check and learn to use that.